# React Native application becomes unresponsive/crashes upon state change

Tags: react-native

I am building an application for iPad with React-Native, when a User clicks a button then a Modal is to appear.

The Modal begins life being hidden, the parent component then sets a `state` boolean variable to determine whether or not to show the Modal.

Here's my code, please ignore imports that are not yet used.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Modal, Text, Button } from "react-native";

const PopupModal = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <Modal transparent={true} visible={props.visible}>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            height: 386,
            width: 355,
            backgroundColor: "#FFF",
            borderRadius: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Button onPress={() => {}} title="Save" />
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default PopupModal;
```

Here's the parent Component

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      videos: [],
      offset: {
        y: 0,
        x: 0
      },
      showPopupModal: false,
      selectedVideo: {
        id: null,
        reflectiveStatement: null,
      }
    };
  }
  editStatement = (id, reflectiveStatement) => {
    this.setState({
      showPopupModal: true,
      selectedVideo: {
        id,
        reflectiveStatement,
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (<PopupModal visible={this.state.showPopupModal} />
  }
}

export default Home;
```

The `this.state.showPopupModal` is either `true` or `false` but every time I click the button fires `editStatement` my application freezes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was an issue with React `0.42.0`, this issue is resolved as of `0.42.2`